# I tried to find the location of the array's element, but the professor said it was wrong

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int search( int arr[], int size, int num) {

int i, loc;
loc=i;

for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    if (arr[i]==num)
          return loc;
    else 
          return -1;
    }
}
```

can someone tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Ask yourself: When I do `return loc;`, what is the value of `loc`?

Comment: Location of the array? You mean the index of a particular value in the array?

Comment: At the point you return, loc is undefined, because i was undefined when you assigned it.

Comment: You never initialize `loc` to a valid value, so you can assume it stores a "garbage value left in memory." In your example, `i` is the index you are using when iterating the array, so if you are to return the index where `arr[i] == num`, you should return `i` instead of `loc`.

Comment: That `else` is also wrong, since it will ensure that you only ever check the first element of the array. And if `size` is 0 (or less) then you won't return any value at all

Comment: `loc=i;` does not do what you think it does. `c++` is not excel. Instead `loc=i;` is a 1 time assignment not a relationship that gets reevaluated each time a variable changes. You set loc to equal the uninitialized value of `i` before the loop.

Comment: `if (arr[i]==num)` -- Say this out loud: "if the item at location i of the array is equal to num...".  In those words, the location is i, so simply return `i`.  There is no need for a `loc` variable.

Comment: It looks like you over-engineered your attempt.  You don't need a `loc` variable, the `else return -1;` can be totally removed, and after the loop, just `return -1;`.  That would eliminate at least three lines of code to get the program to work.

Comment: `int arr[]` should be `const`. Always put in `const` everywhere unless you can't. And before removing it think if the compiler is not just pointing out an error in your code.  That said don't use `int arr[], int size`, use `std::array`, `std::vector` or at least `std::span`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the shown code as described below.

##### Problem 1

The variables `i` and `loc` are **uninitialized** and using those uninitialized variables(which you did when you wrote `loc = i`) is **undefined behavior**.

##### Problem 2

The logic that you've used for the `for` loop and also for the `if` `else` part is not correctly implemented. In particular, suppose the `for` loop is not entered due to the condition `i<size` being false, then no return statement will be encountered for your non-void returning function again leading to **undefined behavior**.

##### Solution

There is no need to create a variable named `loc`. You can just directly return `i` when the element is found. Moreover there is no need for the `else` block. If the element is not found while iterating through the elements, we just return `-1` after the `for` loop.

```
int search( int arr[], int size, int num) {
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]==num)
              return i;//value found so return i directly 
    }
    return -1; //value was never found 
} 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,33,54,3};
    std::cout<<search(arr, 5, 3)<<std::endl;  //prints 4 
    std::cout<<search(arr, 5, 33)<<std::endl; //prints 2 
    std::cout<<search(arr, 5, 98)<<std::endl; //prints -1 
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Q81yut9ck).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that resolves the issues in your initial code. Let's break it down by commenting the code.

```
int search(int arr[], int size, int num) {

    // Initialize `location` to a value, this is very important
    // In this case, it's okay to initialize to the "not found"
    // value and you can simply `return location` at the end of
    // this function.
    int location = -1;

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {

        // Check to see if `arr[index] == num`
        // If so, we found `num` in `arr` !
        // Otherwise, let the loop continue
        if (arr[index] == num) {

             // Since we found `num` in `arr`, let's store the index
             // by updating our location
             location = index;

             // We found the index we are looking for
             // No need to continue the `for` loop
             break;
        }
        // No need for an `else` here, as it was noted in comments that
        // returning in the `else` block  would exit your loop early
    }

    // Just return `location`. It either stores `-1` of the index of `num`
    return location;
}
```

Take time to review your solution and compare it to this particular solution. The primary issues with your original code were

- You didn't initialize the `loc` variable nor did you ever update it before returning. This results in Undefined Behavior.
- You had an `else` statement that returned `-1` inside your `for` loop, which resulted in the loop only ever iterating a single time

Note that there are several ways to write this function and I've just shown one approach. Consider how you could write something functionally equivalent using your own approach.

Also note that you could simplify this code to not use a `location` variable altogether, as in the answer provided by @AnoopRana. I've left the use of the `location` variable in my example since it seemed to be closer to what you were originally going for. This solution is verbose in an attempt to help you understand more thoroughly what the algorithm is doing.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream> 
int search(int arr[], int n , int element)
{ 
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (arr[i] == element) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
 
    if (i < n)
    {
        return i;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 33, 54, 98 };
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int element;
    std::cout<<"Enter element to search for ";
    std::cin>>element;
    std::cout<<search(arr,n,element);
    
}
```

Comment: This is effectively the same solution as what AnoopRana provided but without any context. Also, code only answers are generally frowned upon. Consider giving some context as to _why_ the changes you've made resolve the OP's original question.